# Set Card content visible only on hover with Gatsby + Bootstrap React + scss module

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-bootstrap

First, the stack I'm using:
 - React: Gatsby
 - Typescript
 - Scss (using module for each component)
 - React Bootstrap

I'm trying to show the content of a React Bootstrap Card only when the mouse hovers over it. The problem is that I am using Gatsby modules for scss, and I cannot find the way to directly access the .card-img-overlay class to change its hover properties, since a module would add its name to the class.

My solution was to wrap a div around it. However it doesn't work. The content is hidden but nothing happens when the mouse hovers it. Here is the code:

projectCard.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import styles from './projectCard.module.scss'

interface ProjectInfo {
  title: string
  description: string
  imageSrc: any
}

const ProjectCard = (project: ProjectInfo) => (
  <Card className="bg-dark text-white">
    <Card.Img src={project.imageSrc} alt="Card image" />
    <div className={styles.cardContent}>
      <Card.ImgOverlay>
        <Card.Title> {project.title} </Card.Title>
        <Card.Text> {project.description} </Card.Text>
      </Card.ImgOverlay>
    </div>
  </Card>
)
export default ProjectCard
```

projectCard.module.scss

```
.cardContent {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cardContent:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please reproduce this issue on https://codesandbox.io/ or any other platform? So that I can look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution with the help of a previous comment (someone erased the comment.. but thanks anyways!)

I followed this codepen: https://codepen.io/askibinski/pen/RwWwxxO

```
<Card className={styles['card']}>
    <Card.Img src={project.imageSrc} alt="Card image" className={styles['card-content-image']} />

    <div>
      <Card.ImgOverlay className={styles['card-content']}>
        <Card.Title className={styles['card-content-text']}> {project.title} </Card.Title>
        <Card.Text className={styles['card-content-text']}> {project.description} </Card.Text>
        <Card.Text className={styles['card-content-text']}> {project.technologies} </Card.Text>
      </Card.ImgOverlay>
    </div>
  </Card>
```

Note that I couldn't directly access the Bootstrap elements, so I created class for each of them. Also, gatsby has a camelCase convention, but since it doesn't go well with css standards I overwrote that by adding to gatsby-config.js

```
'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
      options: {
        cssLoaderOptions: {
          camelCase: false,
        },
      },
    }
```

However, that is just a band-aid fix for the problem. I still want to access the React Bootstrap variables if possible. For example, I want to center the Card.Img. I have tried using a className, but it doesn't have access to the image itself.

And here is the code trying to access the React Bootstrap name, but it doesn't work

```
.card-img {
  // any type of css here doesn't have any effect
}
```